# History.js and reloading Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, history.js

So I'm using the [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/) plugin to load pages in my Wordpress theme via AJAX.  I've been successful in doing so and have the entire loading feature working fine.  However, I have many scripts working in the same file and they of course do not get loaded on the state change.

Here's (a very brief) version of my `functions.js` file to explain:

```
(function($){})(window.jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
    /* THIS IS CODE RELATIVE TO MY HOME PAGE ONLY */
    $projects = $("#projects");
    $projects.append($(".contact"));

    $projects.isotope({
        itemSelector : '.item',
        layoutMode : 'masonry'
    });
    /* END PREVIOUS BLOCK */

    /* BEGIN HISTORY.JS IMPLEMENTATION */

    var History = window.History,
        State = History.getState();

    $('.nav a, .leftHold a').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var path = $(this).attr('href');
        var title = $(this).text();
        History.pushState('ajax', title, path);
    });

    History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function() {
        load_site_ajax();
    });

    function load_site_ajax() {
        State = History.getState();
        $('body, html').animate({ scrollTop : 0 }, 250, function() {
            $("#article").animate({ left : -1*$(window).width() }, 250, function() {
                $(this).load(State.url + ' #article', function() {
                    $(".nav li").each(function() {
                        $(this).removeClass("current_page_item").removeClass("current_page_parent").removeClass("current_page_ancestor");
                    }).promise().done(function() {
                        $(".nav a").each(function() {
                            if(State.title.indexOf($(this).text()) != -1) {
                                $(this).parent().addClass('current_page_item');
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }).promise().done(function() { $(this).css("left", $(window).width()).animate({ left : 0 }, 250); });
            });
        });
    }

    /* END HISTORY.JS */
});
```

I load this `functions.js` file at the **end** of my document, just before the closing `body` tag.  I can tell that whenever I change browser states, the code in `$(document).ready();` doesn't run again, therefore Isotope and none of my other Javascripts load again.

**QUESTION:**

How should I ensure that the code in `functions.js` runs every time the pushstate is initiated by History.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you'll need to execute the `ready` code again.  Wrap your initialization code in a function:

```
$(document).ready(initializePage);

function initializePage() {
    /* THIS IS CODE RELATIVE TO MY HOME PAGE ONLY */
    ... 
}
```

And then, when `"statechange"` fires, you can call `initializePage()` again.

You will also need to make sure the History code only runs once, so put that code in a separate function:

```
$(document).ready(setupHistory);

function setupHistory() {
    /* BEGIN HISTORY.JS IMPLEMENTATION */

    var History = window.History,
        State = History.getState();
    });
    ....
}
```

Comment: I can't get this to do anything different.  I've implemented the second code block you gave and that's set up just fine.  However, I don't know what you mean by triggering the ready event, where and when would I do that?

Comment: Never mind about the trigger, I didn't realize that jQuery auto-triggers the `ready` event when you attach to it.  So, I updated my answer, but to be honest, I'm not entirely sure I get the question anymore.

Comment: @cereallarceny I updated my answer :)  I think I finally understood the question.

Comment: Brilliant answer.  Thank you SO MUCH!  I ended up running initializePage() inside of the `load()` callback before I actually move the `#article` out, change content, and move it back in.  Thanks!